# Can we check shiny applications using testthat and usethis

Tags: r, shiny

is there a way to check the below applications. This is a sample application to display selected rows. But in general is there a way to acheive this. For example the below code is perfect. Suppose I may some errors in this and I need to check all in once. Can we do that? I have also pasted the error code down

Correct

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- basicPage(
  mainPanel(DT::dataTableOutput('mytable')),
  textOutput("selected")
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {

  mydata <- reactive({mtcars})

  output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable(    
    datatable(mydata())
  ) 

  selectedRow <- eventReactive(input$mytable_rows_selected,{
    row.names(mtcars)[c(input$mytable_rows_selected)]
  })

  output$selected <- renderText({ 
    selectedRow()
  })
}
runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

Wrong/Error code

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- basicPage(
  mainPanel(DT::dataTableOutput('mytable')),
  textOutput("selected")
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {

  mydata <- reactive({mtcars})

  output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable(    
    datatable(mydata())
  ) 

  selectedRow <- eventReactive(input$mytable_rows_selected,{
    row.names(mtcars)[c(input$[mytable_rows_selected])]
  })

  output$selected <- renderText({ 
    selectedRow
  })
}
runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the package `shinytest` to test my shiny apps. `shinytest` uses `phantomJS` to manipulate the app (i.e. simulate button presses etc.)

An entry in `testthat/test-shinyapp.R` looks something like:

```
test_that("Shiny template works", {
  app <- shinytest::ShinyDriver$new("Path_To_ShinyApp/"))

  # plot changes
  # first click makes plot
  testthat::expect_false(length(grepl("^(data:image/png;base64)",
                                      app$getAllValues()$output$plot1$src)) > 0)
  app$setInputs(apply = "click")
  testthat::expect_true(length(grepl("^(data:image/png;base64)",
                                      app$getAllValues()$output$plot1$src)) > 0)
  testthat::expect_true(grepl("^(data:image/png;base64)",
                              app$getAllValues()$output$plot1$src))

  # are subsequent changes applied?
  testthat::expect_identical(app$getAllValues()$input$xVar, "mpg")
  testthat::expect_true(
    grepl("      mpg             cyl", app$getAllValues()$output$summary1))
  app$setInputs(xVar = "drat")
  app$setInputs(apply = "click")
  testthat::expect_true(
    grepl("      drat            cyl", app$getAllValues()$output$summary1))

  # # test for reactive
  # shinytest::expectUpdate(app, xVar = "wt", output = "plot1" )
  # shinytest::expectUpdate(app, yVar = "drat", output = "plot1" )
  # shinytest::expectUpdate(app, xVar = "cyl", output = "summary1" )
  # shinytest::expectUpdate(app, yVar = "mpg", output = "summary1" )

  # cleanup
  app$stop()
  unlink(paste0(ws2us(testDir),"_ShinyApp"), recursive = TRUE)
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. i have couple of questions. Do I need to created a folder called testthat and then create a r file called test-shinyapp.R and execute above code in this file?. I mean i just need to understand the folder structure

Comment: Assuming you’re in a package directory, just run `usethis::use_test("name")` to create a test file, and set up all the other infrastructure you need.

Comment: Hi I tried with this. But I get this error ````Error: `use_testthat()` is designed to work with packages.
Project 'Analysis' is not an R package.````

Comment: Are you in a package or not?

Comment: I do not think so. I created a project and inside that I am in. Not sure what exactly the difference between pacakge and project. Can you please guide me

Comment: A package is a project with a formalized structure, so it can be build as a package and loaded into the environment using `library(package_name)`.

At some level, all a package means is to put your R code in a directory called R/ and then add some metadata in a DESCRIPTION file. (-[Hadley Wickham](https://github.com/r-lib/testthat/issues/659#issuecomment-340816578))
`testthat` is best used within a package. But you can just put the `test-foo.R` files in a `tests` directory and run the files by hand.
I think you have to decide if you want to put your code into a package, and then ask again.

Comment: Thanks. Will check.